# Cannot boot Ubuntu or Windows 7 after install Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on a HP Z620 workstation, which is originally installed with Window 7. However, after I installed Ubuntu, I cannot login into both systems, and the startup indicates to startup repair.

After I run the startup repair, I can login Window 7 again, but not Ubuntu.

I also tried to re-install the grub from Ubuntu boot CD using the method from this [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UphQtWRNsfQ), and the same problem still remains.

I guess the Ubuntu system is successfully installed along with the grub, but the grub may be installed in the wrong location. Seems the system's boot location is hidden in some other locations. But I am not clear about it? The following is a photo of my partition information, and I am installing the Ubuntu system on `/dev/sdg7`.

The disk partition information:

[image]

EDIT:
I have tried the boot-repair following instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). After that, I can boot the Ubuntu system. However, I cannot find the Windows 7 in the menu.

Comment: I have tried the boot-repair following instruction here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

After that, I can boot the Ubuntu system. However, I cannot find the Windows 7 in the menu.

Comment: Boot into ubuntu,openup the terminal,run 'sudo os-prober' and post it's output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the Linux partitions was damaged, so you need to reinstall Ubuntu again and install grub2 into /dev/sdg **not /dev/sdgx!**!! I an very intresting in where is /dev/sda? /dev/sdb? etc.

Comment: Actually, I have re-installed Ubuntu several times, all end up with failure. I also have tried to simply re-install grub2, and extract into **/dev/sdg**, it does not work either. I am also curious about /dev/sda, and /dev/sdb, but now I cannot access that computer until next Monday.